# C++ Function executing for a map object but not changing value

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map with pointers to objects(for polymorphism) they use a string ID as their key. Each of these objects contain an object inside them, when I try to modify the value of the contained object, the function works but as soon as it leaves the function the value is unchanged. I thought it might be to do with the iterator or the get method being constant but I've changed that and still having the same problem.

```
   void System::addUserFunds()
{
    string userID;
    float fundsToAdd;

    cout << "Which ID: ";
    cin >> userID;
    cin.ignore();
    if (userFound(userID))
    {
        map<string, User*>::iterator it = UsersMap.find(userID); // 
        cout << "How much do you want to add to " << 
        it->second->getUserID() << "'s card: $";            
        cin >> fundsToAdd;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "\nCurrent funds  user is : $" << it->second->getCard()().getFunds();
        if (it->second->getCard().addFunds(fundsToAdd) == true)
        {
            cout << "\nAdded $" << fundsToAdd << " to " << userID << "'s card";
            cout << "\nFunds remaining for " << userID << ": $" << it->second->
            getCard().getFunds();
        }
        else 
        {
            displayMenu();
        }

    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "\nSorry, this user does not exist";
        displayMenu();
    }
}
```

The addFunds() method inside the Card object is

```
bool Card::addFunds(float extraFunds)
{
    if ((int)extraFunds % 5 == 0)
    {
        if ((funds + extraFunds) <= Card::getMaxLimit())
        {
            cout << "\nEntering addFunds function";
            funds += extraFunds;
            cout << "\n Funds are now: $" << funds;
            displayFunds();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nSorry, max funds allowed is $100.00\n";
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nSorry, you can only add in multiples of $5.00\n";
        return false;
    }


}
```

So when I run this, it definitely has the right User selected, it enters the function, it modifies the funds value but as it exits the function - the user's card funds are unchanged.

Appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: How is `User::getCard` declared? Does it return a `Card` by value or by reference?

Comment: Card User::getCard()
{
 return card; 
}

Comment: Then you return *by value*, which means that the `Card` instance is *copied* and you only perform the operations on the copy and not the original. You should return *by reference*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason for this behavior seems to be

```
User::getCard()
```

My speculation is that you are returning object by value

```
Card User::getCard ()
```

so `addFunds()` would be applied to that value rather than original object.

Make sure you return a reference from `getCard().`

```
Card& User::getCard()
```